# Excel formula to give cell value from 2 columns BEFORE a matched cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a value in A1 and an array in B1:X1.  I know that the value in A1 exists in the array.

Is there a formula that will find the A1 match in B1:X1 and return the value of the cell located 2 columns before the match?

Ex.

```
 A1 = "BOB"      F1 = "BOB"
```

I want a formula in B1 that will find that A1=F1 and then write the value from D1 to B1, since D is 2 columns before F.

Comment: You need to rethink your specifications. If your formula is going to be in `B1`, you cannot have your array start in `B1`.  You need to be sure that the cell that is two columns before  the matched cell is not `B1` else you will have a circular reference. So you shouldn't start searching before `E1`.

Answer (score 2):

If A1=C1, but A is 2 columns before C, then what's the result?

If A1 will be equal to values from D to X, then please check the formula `=VLOOKUP(A1,$B1:$F1,MATCH(A1,$B1:$F1,0)-2,TRUE)`.

Answer (score 1):

Want the formula to be in cell `B1`?
If so, then you can use
`=XLOOKUP(A1,E1:X1,C1:V1)`

Comment: A slight variation of this answer, if the `-2` needs to be dynamic: `=XLOOKUP(A1, C1:X1, OFFSET(C1:X1, 0, -2))`